# In Scala - Converting a case class List into a List of tuples

Tags: scala

i have a case class

```
case class table(a: String, b: Option[String])
```

and i have a list of that type - lets call it list1

```
val list1: List[table] = tabele.get() // just filling the list from an SQL
```

now I want to change the list of "table" into a simple list of (String,Option[String])
What i allready found on this board was how to convert a case class into a tuple 
like that:

```
case class table(a:String, b:Int)
val (str, in) =  table.unapply(table("test", 123)).get()
```

But i don't know how to use this on a List :(
I tried something with foreach like:

```
val list2: List[(String, Option[String])] = Nil
list1.foreach( x => list2 :: table.unapply(x).get())
'error (String,Option[String]) does not take parameters
```

so my question would be -> how can I use unapply on every tuple of a List?

thank in advance

---

PS: I actually want to change the type of the list because I want to use ".toMap" on that list
- like:

```
val map1 = list1.toMap.withDefaultValue(None)
```

with the error:

```
Cannot prove that models.table <:<(T,U)
```

and it would work for a (String, Option[String]) list

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to convert every element of a list giving another list. You need `foreach`'s cousin, `map`:

Try:

```
 list1.map(table.unapply).flatten
```

which is a better way of writing:

```
 list1.map( tbl => table.unapply(tbl) ).flatten
```

Another way would be

```
 list1.map(table.unapply(_).get)
```

Which is shorthand for

```
 list1.map( tbl => table.unapply(tbl).get )
```

And just to throw in a version using `for`: (which is illustrative of how `unapply` is used under the hood in `for` comprehensions)

```
 for (table(s,ms) <- list1) yield (s, ms)
```