# How to convert a list of case class data to List of string data?

Tags: scala

I have a `List` of case class data. How can I convert it to a `List` of `string`?

This is my `List` of `WhitelistRule`: `List(WhitelistRule("ruleName","123456789012")`.

This is what I expect the output to be: `List("ruleName","123456789012")`.

This is how `WhitelistRule` is defined:

```
object Whitelist {
    case class WhitelistRule(accountId: String, ruleName: String) extends Whitelist
}
```

Comment: You can refer to this question [In Scala - Converting a case class List into a List of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15113269/8630846) as both are same to some extent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flatMap for it:

`list.flatMap(rule => List(rule.ruleName, rule.accountId))`

to list objects:

```
val list = List("ruleName1", "accountId1", "ruleName2", "accountId2")
list.grouped(2)
  .map(fields => WhitelistRule(fields.head, fields(1)))
  .toList // List(WhitelistRule("ruleName1", "accountId1"), WhitelistRule("ruleName2", "accountId2"))
```

Comment: Thanks Boris, how can I convert that list of string to case class?